# Частичная проблема с кодировкой после обрезания текста функцией

Tags: php

Функция режет описание статьи в зависимости от длины заголовка и добавляет многоточие в конце:

```
function cut_main_preview_card($art_title, $full_des){
    $count_art_title = strlen($art_title);
    if($count_art_title>100){
        $count_full_des = strlen($full_des);
        if($count_full_des>350){

            $lenght = 350;
            $b = mb_substr($full_des, 0, $lenght);
            $new_des = $b.'&#8230;';

        }else {
            $new_des = $full_des;
        }

    }elseif($count_art_title<=100){
        $count_full_des = strlen($full_des);
        if($count_full_des>450){

            $lenght = 450;
            $b = mb_substr($full_des, 0, $lenght);
            $new_des = $b.'&#8230;';

        }else {
            $new_des = $full_des;
        }
    }
    return $new_des;
}
```

Проблема состоит в том, что, если обрезанный текст заканчивается пробелом, то после пробела ставится многоточие и проблем нет, но, если обрезается часть слова, то между обрезанным словом и многоточием ставится знак вопроса в чёрном ромбе, как это бывает при проблемах с кодировкой. В чём может быть дело? Весь остальной текст обработанного функцией описания прописан кириллицей без проблем.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `strlen()` использовать `mb_strlen()`. Тем более, что `mb_substr()` Вы уже используете. И еще: а нельзя обрезанный текст продлить до следуюшего пробела? тогда и выглядеть будет лучше....

Comment: @Torawhite, вы кодировку-то для функции укажите. Похожие вопросы http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444529/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-substr-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0/ и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/369574/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-php

Comment: Спасибо! Да будет лучше, только я пока не додумался, как это сделать. Если поможете, то буду благодарен. А при текущем варианте можно решить проблему удалением последнего символа в строке, как оказалось...(но это не совсем грамотно, не спорю) $b = mb_substr($full_des, 0, $lenght);
            $str = substr($b,0,-1);
            $new_des = $str.'&#8230;';

Comment: Упс, `strlen()` не заметил :) Но для нее аналогично.

Comment: Visman, спасибо, помогло. Заодно заменил strlen() на mb_strlen()

Comment: Вопрос можно закрывать как решенный? Или вы свое решение опубликуете как ответ? Так можно делать. Или @cyadvert оформит ответ?

Comment: Спасибо! Да, можно закрывать, как решённый.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно функция strlen возвращает не то что вам надо. Попробуйте mb_strlen (string str [, string encoding]), вторым аргументом передается кодировка текста. А также, перед обрезанием текста функцией mb_substr(), предварительно обработайте ее (текст) функцией strip_tags(), удаляет html элементы из текста.